# Seeking Guidance on Creating a LaTeX .cls File

Tags: cls

I am a beginner in LaTeX, primarily familiar with using pre-defined .cls files.
However, I am interested in creating my own .cls file to meet specific formatting requirements.
Could someone provide guidance on how to embark on this task?
I am looking for technical and learning resources, such as books, courses, and reference materials, as LaTeX documentation seems relatively scarce compared to other programming languages.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: start from texdoc clsguide which is distributed with every latex release

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.